# How to sleep inside a for loop after 1000 iterations in python

Tags: python

I'm using a for loop to iterate over a pandas dataframe column thusly:

```
for i in df['column']:
    try:
        do_stuff_with_column_data
        time.sleep(10)
    except:
        continue
```

How can I change the code to do stuff with data for 1000 rows and then wait for ten seconds and continue after that?

Comment: Using a for loop to iterate over a column is usually much less efficient than operating on the whole column at once. You could break it into chunks of 1000 cells first if necessary. What are you doing with the column data?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `enumerate` function in your `for`-loop this way you will get the index number of the iteration you are currently in and change the code as shown here.

```
for index, i in enumerate(df['column']):
    do_stuff_with_column_data(i)

    if index % 1000 == 0:
        time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
row_processed = 0

for i in df['column']:
    try:
        do_stuff_with_column_data
        row_processed += 1
        if row_processed == 1000:
            row_processed = 0
            time.sleep(10)
    except:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display 1000 rows from data frame and then have 10 sec sleep as well using below code:-

```
df1 = df.head(1000)
time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the enumerate function to loop over the elements, but also get an index of the elements.

```
import numpy as np
import time

df = np.random.rand(10000)

for i, elm in enumerate(df):
    try:
        print(elm)
        if i == 999:
            print('sleeping for 10 seconds')
            time.sleep(10)
    except:
        continue
```